# Does "Predicate" includes object, complement and modifiers?

Tags: subjects, modifiers, objects, complements, predicate

I'm currently studying the "Sentence Structure" for the English language. I've found varied information in this regard.

Some sources says that the sentence consist of five components: `Subject + Predicate + Object + Complement + Modifier`

Some other sources say that it consist of only two components: `Subject + Predicate`.

Now, I'm confused, whether predicate actually includes the object, complement, and modifier in itself or not. If yes, why some sources mention them separately from the "Predicate"?

Comment: If you are taking a course, you **must** ask a tutor for the terminology they use, or you will get hopelessly confused. But be aware that there are conflicting terminologies in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sentence may have a subject and predicate, only:

> I know.

The predicate 'know' does not include other elements, because that sentence needs no more. The statement is complete. Only if the sentence continues can we see object, complement, modifier.

A verb is called intransitive when it makes sense (like the verb know) without an object. That is why there is no object in the sentence "I know." Only a transitive takes an object (which may have modifiers).

Note there are even sentences with one word, like when grandma calls you.

> Eat!

Then, we say that the subject 'You' is understood -- we know who she is addressing.

Answer (score 2):

*Predicate* is [a term from Logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) which gets used in talking about language. On the other
hand, *Verb, Subject, Complement, Modifier,* and *Object* are terms about language.
Naturally they don't compute together very well.

In a normal English declarative sentence, there is a subject (which is a noun phrase), and there is a verb phrase, which is the predicate of the sentence.

The prototypic kind of predicate is a verb; if the predicate is a predicate noun
or a predicate adjective, we have to use an auxiliary verb *be*:

- *Bill **ran**.*
- *Bill **is tired**.*
- *Bill **is a runner**.*

All non-auxiliary verbs are the heads of predicates. That's why there are "predicate nouns" and "predicate adjectives" but not *predicate verbs.

Loosely speaking, we could say that the predicates in the preceding examples are *run, tired,* and *runner*; strictly speaking, they would be the full [Verb Phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/lVPguide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a universally accepted definition, but the one I've seen most often is that "predicate" includes the verb and object. This is also the convention used by *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, at least if [section 5 of this summary](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html) is correct. (I don't have *CGEL* in front of me, but the summary agrees with what I can remember.) "Complement" is used for the "object" of a linking verb, as in *Oswald was **the assassin*** or *she looked **stunning***. Adjuncts and such are options.