# Theory for Predicate and Verb Phrase

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I found this https://english.stackexchange.com/a/376027/223821 answered by @YosefBaskin. Can anyone please tell me theory from book suitable with his explanation? Especially, about the predicate noun and predicate adjective in relation to verb phrase.

Next question is which one is the head if the verb phrase consists of predicate noun or predicate adjective?

Thank you, everyone. :)

Comment: YB makes a number of unsurprising points in his answer. Which ones are you concerned about. The head of an X-phrase will be an X. So the head of verb phrase will be a verb.

Comment: @deadrat So then, the X (head) could be the auxiliary verb "be" (ex: am, is, are)?

Comment: Sure. In the sentence *I am very happy*, the subject is the noun phrase consisting of the pronoun *I* (which is necessarily its head), and the predicate is the verb phrase *am very happy*, with head *am*.

Comment: @deadrat Thank you.. Sorry, but do you have/know any references for book in relation to that explanation?

Comment: It is standard grammar. Predicate nouns/adjectives are predicative complements of the verb. They refer to the subject ("Ed is a teacher/kind") or the object ("I consider Ed a friend/kind").

Comment: I like the exposition in *Oxford Modern English Grammar* by Bas Aarts.

Comment: @deadrat Nice.. Thank you so much. Anyway, another question is since phrase is not always group of words (it can be one word like "I" which is noun phrase), is there any definition about what exactly phrase is according to theorist?

Comment: It is a slight exaggeration to say that there are as many terminologies as there are linguists. As Huddleston and Pullam point out in *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, it is "tedious to have to talk about 'nouns and noun phrases'" to accommodate nouns that appear alone for the former and nouns that appear with other words for the latter. So they talk about phrases being a head with zero or more dependents, with the *zero* covering the case of a phrase that consists only of a head.

Comment: @deadrat Thanks. I'm sorry if I ask you on and on, but I still have questions. What is clause? What makes it different with sentence?

Comment: @user223821 A clause has a subject and a verb; an independent clause is one that expresses a complete thought; a sentence is a set of related clauses, at least one of which is an independent clause.

Comment: @deadrat In relation to clauses, do you mind to check this http://english.stackexchange.com/q/377177/223821 and tell me your opinion about it? Thank you so much.

Comment: @deadrat Hello! I wanted to ask you something. "I wrote an email and sent it to her." In that sentence, do you think it has one or two independent clause(s)? At first, I thought it has two main clauses since it can be described as "I wrote an email and (I) sent it to her". So, it'd be 2 main clauses: "I wrote an email" & "(I) sent it to her". Yet, I doubted and thought that it only has one main clause because the "I" is not clearly stated/written. What do you think? Thank you in advance.